# Qgis Web Client feature jump to layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client

It is possible to add a new feature to qgis web client?
I would like to add jump/zoom to selected layer. I tried to add something like this using ZoomToExtent feature with fixed coordinates, but this didn't work. I think I could get extent coordinates of selected layer but I can't pass it to ZoomToExtent. Guidelines would be nice.